# overloading the destination url of privatemsg

Tags: privatemsg

I have a privatemsg message form, and I need to alter the success URL that loads when a message is sent. What is the easiest way to go about doing this? The code i'm using is more or less based on the example code [used here](http://drupal.org/node/624528):

```
 module_load_include('pages.inc','privatemsg');dru
 print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('privatemsg_new'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and find your forms `$form_id`. Then supply a [#redirect](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) FAPI attribute like, `$form['#redirect'] = 'my-custom-thankyou-page';` and be sure to make your custom page as a drupal Page, module callback, View etc.

Comment: I've set the redirect in question using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter through a module, and its still not functional. The module in question is one used to display a variety of pages pertaining to user information, and has a template that explicitly references the above privatemsg form

`function example_user_form_privatemsg_new_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    
    $form['#redirect'] = "classes";
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'classes';
}`